# In how many ways can I distribute "n" candies to 3 children such that each gets at least 1 candy and at least 1 child should get more than others

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension, combinations, permutation

How many different ways can I distribute "n" candies to m = 3 children such that each one gets at least 1 candy and at least 1 child should get more candies than others?

For eg: No. of candies = 6,
Total ways = 9
[1,4,1] , [1,1,4] , [4,1,1] , [1,2,3] , [1,3,2] and so on....     total ways = 9.

My code in Python:

```
import itertools

n = int(input())
arr = []

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        for k in range(1,n+1):
            if (i+j+k == n) and (i!=j or j!=k):
                if sorted(list(set(itertools.permutations([i,j,k],3)))) not in arr:
                    arr.append(sorted(list(set(itertools.permutations([i,j,k],3)))))

print(arr)       
arr1 = [arr[i][j] for i in range(len(arr)) for j in range(len(arr[i]))]
print(arr1)
print(len(arr1))
```

I solved it on my own even though I am relatively new to advanced programming and I know that my code is not optimized. I would like to optimize it as well as make the list of the different ways in a single line using list comprehension.

My list comprehension has errors:

```
arr = [sorted(list(set(itertools.permutations([i,j,k],3))) if ((i+j+k == n) and (i!=j or j!=k) and sorted(list(set(itertools.permutations([i,j,k],3))))) not in arr for i in range(1,n+1) for j in range(1, n+1) for k in range(1,n+1)]
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you avoid too many nested conditions and loops. And is there a reason why you want your answer to involve a list comprehension? I like using them too, but beyond a point they become too long to, um... comprehend. Here's an alternative solution that uses fewer loops, avoids long list comprehensions and is easier to read -- to my eyes, at least.

```
In [29]: from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement

In [30]: def all_valid_permutations(candies, members):
    ...:     combos = combinations_with_replacement(range(1, candies), members)
    ...:     valid_permutations = set()
    ...:     for item in combos:
    ...:         for perm in permutations(item):
    ...:             if sum(perm) == candies and len(set(perm)) >= members-1:
    ...:                 valid_permutations.add(perm)
    ...:
    ...:     return valid_permutations
    ...:

In [31]: all_valid_permutations(6, 3)
Out[31]:
{(1, 1, 4),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 2),
 (1, 4, 1),
 (2, 1, 3),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 2),
 (3, 2, 1),
 (4, 1, 1)}
```

If you know your basic combinatorics you can guess what the imported functions do. (Or you can read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement), if you prefer.) I can't guarantee performance, though, without fully knowing your use-case. This is just a quick solution, off the top of my head. I bet you can optimise this further.

Comment: in your solution cases where 2 children have highest candies were also counted. eg. [5,5,2];[5,2,5];[2,5,5] are counted thus for 12 candies,instead of 51 your answer is 54.

Comment: @VFalcon, the question stipulates that "at least 1 child should get more candies than others", and therefore these are valid outcomes. Or have I misunderstood your claim?

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want the number of ways and not all the combinations, this seems more like a math question than a programming question.

The number of ways to distribute n candies to m children, where all children receive at least 1 candy, is just (n - 1)C(m - 1). For a detailed explanation on why, read up on this page in the last section: https://brilliant.org/wiki/identical-objects-into-distinct-bins/#distribution-into-non-empty-bins

"at least 1 child should get more candies than others" can also be understood as "not all children should have the same number of candies". In that case, we just need to subtract the case where all children have the same number of candies from the number of ways calculated, if the number of candies is a multiple of the number of children.

```
from math import comb

n = 6
m = 3

numberOfWays = comb(n - 1, m - 1) - 1 if n % m == 0 else 0
print(numberOfWays)
```